# WP-DEPLOY : Cannot Push database

Tags: deployment, ruby, capistrano

So I've been trying to set up Wp-Deploy for about 3 weeks now :(

I have a digitalocean droplet that I am using for staging and was able to finally get my local environment to deploy the files to the server, however, I cannot get the database commands to work. When I try and backup the database I get the following output

```
    dixon@Sphinx /var/www/html $ bundle exec cap staging db:backup
00:00 db:backup_name
      01 mkdir -p /var/www/vhosts/thedixonbuilds.com/httpdocs/shared/db_backups
    ✔ 01 root@<ip address> 1.748s
      02 wp db export - | gzip > /var/www/vhosts/thedixonbuilds.com/httpdocs/shared/db_backups/20190210165609.sql.gz
      02 /usr/bin/env:
      02 ‘wp’
      02 : No such file or directory
      02
    ✔ 02 root@<ip address> 0.244s
      Downloading db_backups/20190210165609.sql.gz 100.0%
      03 rm /var/www/vhosts/thedixonbuilds.com/httpdocs/shared/db_backups/20190210165609.sql.gz
    ✔ 03 root@<ip address> 0.228s
```

and when I try and run the db:push

```
00:00 db:backup_name
      01 mkdir -p /var/www/vhosts/thedixonbuilds.com/httpdocs/shared/db_backups
    ✔ 01 root@<ip address> 1.399s
      02 mkdir -p db_backups
    ✔ 02 dixon@localhost 0.003s
      03 wp db export - | gzip > db_backups/20190210170146.sql.gz
    ✔ 03 dixon@localhost 0.271s
      Uploading db_backups/20190210170146.sql.gz 100.0%
      04 gzip -c -d /var/www/vhosts/thedixonbuilds.com/httpdocs/shared/db_backups/20190210170146.sql.gz | wp db import -
      04 bash: wp: command not found
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as root@138.68.14.196: gzip exit status: 127
gzip stdout: Nothing written
gzip stderr: bash: wp: command not found


Caused by:
SSHKit::Command::Failed: gzip exit status: 127
gzip stdout: Nothing written
gzip stderr: bash: wp: command not found
/var/www/html/lib/capistrano/tasks/db.rake:148:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/var/www/html/lib/capistrano/tasks/db.rake:147:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:push
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I'm not sure how capistrano achieves the database manipulation or what usr/bin/env  is supposed to contain. Can anyone help me with some leads?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Both of those failed for the same reason. Did you not see the errors?

Here they are:

```
      02 /usr/bin/env:
      02 ‘wp’
      02 : No such file or directory
```

And:

```
gzip stderr: bash: wp: command not found
```

Both times, your script is trying to run the [`wp`](https://wp-cli.org/) command, but it is not installed or not in your PATH. You need to install it first, and second make sure your PATH is set correctly.

Comment: I saw the error it just makes no sense to me since I am new to all of the underlying technologies. I assumed the wp command was built into the same package that all of the other commands that work are. I'll do some more digging and see if I can get it to make sense, thank you.

Comment: @JeremyDixon Eh? The wp-deploy README does say you have to install it first. Go click on the link, install it and then try again.

Comment: Oh wait wp as in wp-cli ? That IS installed and wp:setup worked so I thought everything was okay with that install but I must be wrong. It is probably the PATH like you said